# Does squeezing a vacuum state produces photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

A squeezed vacuum state is produced by applying a squeezing operator $S$ on the vacuum state $|0 \rangle$:

\begin{eqnarray}
S | 0 \rangle = \sum_n C_n |n \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

My question is, from $|0 \rangle$ (which means we have zero photons) we produce the state $| n \rangle$ which has $n$ number of photons. Does it mean we create photons from vacuum by squeezing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but to create photons at a reasonable rate the squeezing has to occur at a speed close to that of light. You may be interested in this paper, *[Observation of the dynamical Casimir effect in a superconducting circuit](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v479/n7373/full/nature10561.html).* The authors used superconducting devices to change the boundary conditions in a waveguide at a high frequency, which is effectively the same as squeezing the vacuum in the waveguide.